# Could not able to penetrate array object name which is in number in jq

Tags: bash, shell, jq

```
{
    "components": {
        "1": [{
                "x": 14,
                "y": 15
            },
            {
                "A": 5,
                "B": 6
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

When I try to access this json via `jq` command. I'm getting an error stating cannot iterate over null (null).

If I change that object array ( `"1"` to alphabet say `"X"`) then it is working fine.

Could you guide me what i'm doing wrong here.**

Comment: What is your failing `jq` filter?

Comment: You need to show the `jq` command you're trying to run.

Comment: When I give this command   jq '.components.1[ ].x' x.json is failing here. If i edit the same json with some alphabet it is working fine.  jq '.components.<alphabet>[ ].x' x.json

Answer (score 1):

I'm not getting the same error, but:

```sh
$ jq '.components.1[0].x' file.json
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected LITERAL, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.components.1[0].x
jq: 1 compile error
```

You can use brackets:

```sh
$ jq '.components["1"][0].x' file.json
14
```

Answer (score 1):

`.components` is an object, not an array, thus the field names are strings, not numbers (as an arrays keys would be). Yet, you can have numbers (in strings) as object filed names, but you have to treat them as strings.

```sh
jq '.components["1"]'
# or
jq '.components."1"'
```

```json
[
  {
    "x": 14,
    "y": 15
  },
  {
    "A": 5,
    "B": 6
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/MWM-M9Owan)

In contrast, `.components["1"]` is an array and you can access its elements by numbers.

```sh
jq '.components["1"][1]'
# or
jq '.components."1"[1]'
```

```json
{
  "A": 5,
  "B": 6
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/x6wqll8U6J)

Therefore, this should be what you are trying to do:

```sh
jq '.components."1"[ ].x'
```

```json
14
null
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/GOk211ZJX-)

Comment: My mistake... Great. Thanks a lot !!!